# Estimated job completion time in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

How can we check the expected time to complete a task when it is just submitted to Map slot in Hadoop ?
We are trying for an algorithm and need help on determining the estimated time a job will need to complete when it is submitted to the Map slot in Hadoop.
Is it possible to determine just after submitting the job and how?
Some researchers have used estimated time of job completion time while the job is in progress.

Comment: There are way too many undetermined variables to consider here: Cluster capacity, cluster availability at time of submit, operation complexity, data or I/O latency to name a few.  Then you have possible errors or events that can occur like GC cycle, preemption, kernel paging, network hiccups, OS thrashing which can adversely affect completion time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If the cluster capacity and its availability is known and assuming the complexity of the job to be average and other factors ideal.What could be a formalized possible logic to compute the estimate time for a job ?

Comment: You might as well use SLS if that's what you want.  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-sls/SchedulerLoadSimulator.html